# Spring Reactive - reuse Mono value

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a sequence of `Mono` transformations using `flatMap`. I managed to simplify my production code to this test case:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    AtomicInteger iCounter = new AtomicInteger(1);
    Mono<String> iValueMono = Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {
        int iValue = iCounter.getAndIncrement();
        System.out.println("iValueMono CALL: " + iValue);
        return String.valueOf(iValue);
    });

    Mono<String> resultMono = Mono.just("X")
            .flatMap(append(iValueMono))
            .flatMap(append(iValueMono));

    StepVerifier.create(resultMono)
            .consumeNextWith(result -> assertThat(result).isEqualTo("X11"))
            .expectComplete()
            .verify();
}

private Function<String, Mono<String>> append(Mono<String> sMono) {
    return s -> sMono.map(v -> s + v);
}
```

This prints:

```
iValueMono CALL: 1
iValueMono CALL: 2

org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :"X11"
Actual   :"X12"
```

I thought - I see now that it was incorrect - that each time I map the `iValueMono` in the `append()` call, the supplier is re-executed to produces a new value. I cannot change in the production code how the `iValueMono` is implemented (eg. to make it stateful to store the value). How can I implement this so that the value supplier is only called once and I get the final result "X11"?

Of course, I'm interested in a non-blocking, reactive way to do this.

Comment: Do you have to use Mono.fromSupplier?

Comment: @vanillaSugar No, I don't, this is for test purposes. In the production code this comes from a reactive HTTP call using WebClient - this is why I want to avoid calling it multiple times. So the iValueMono result is dynamic and can change each time it's evaluated - I want to evaluate it only once (even if mono is mapped multiple times)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [`Mono.cache()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#cache--) is the answer:

> Turn this Mono into a hot source and cache last emitted signals for further Subscriber.

Using it:

```
Mono<String> iValueMono = Mono.fromSupplier(() -> {
    int iValue = iCounter.getAndIncrement();
    System.out.println("iValueMono CALL: " + iValue);
    return String.valueOf(iValue);
}).cache();
```

delivers the desired result of calling the supplier only once.

Comment: This is really nice to know

Comment: The documentation also says this: "Once the first subscription is made to this Mono, the source is subscribed to and the signal will be cached, indefinitely. This process cannot be cancelled." Isn't it a problem? A memory/resource leak? I might need the value 2 times, and then what? As I understand the doc, it is kept forever. Or am I mistaken?

Comment: @HonzaZidek "indefinitely" means here "for the lifetime of this Mono object", so until it's garbage collected. That is to the other overloaded versions of the `cache()` method which have TTL parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your test and now iValueMono is executed only once it seems:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    AtomicInteger iCounter = new AtomicInteger(0);
    Mono<String> iValueMono = getMono(iCounter.incrementAndGet());

    Mono<String> resultMono = Mono.just("X")
        .flatMap(append(iValueMono))
        .flatMap(append(iValueMono));

    StepVerifier.create(resultMono)
        .consumeNextWith(result -> assertEquals(result, "X11"))
        .expectComplete()
        .verify();
}

private Mono<String> getMono(int x) {
    System.out.println("Called");
    return Mono.just(String.valueOf(x));
}
```

What do you think of it? Does it help?

Comment: Thanks, but not quite - I get the `iValueMono` from a service call, I cannot modify how it's implemented. Using `Mono.just()` oversimplifies things, since the emitted item is captured at Mono instantiation time.